# iOS Library for Dates Natural Language Processing?

Tags: ios, nlp, nsdate

Is there any option to detect natural language strings like:

- "Every other Sunday"
- "Mondays at 5-6pm from 20/9 until 30/11"

which will covert it to an object with date, hour, repeat rule, repeat start & end, etc...

Is it possible to detect such things on iOS?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know any solution written in Objective-C, but you can probably have a look at this JavaScript project: https://github.com/banderson623/nl-date
The code is easy to understand and short, it won't be hard to translate into Objective-C.

It claims to parse this kind of strings, though I haven't tested it yet:

> "Meet with the Soccer Board Thursday 14th at 5:30pm at Gilbert Elementary School"
>
> "Soccer Board meeting 8/15 5:30pm Gilbert Elementary School"
>
> "Discuss soccer goals next tuesday in Campfire"

Let us know if you write an equivalent in Objective-C :)

Comment: The problem with this is that it can't understand recurring events, but thanks :)

Comment: I hoped you'll make it smarter and share with us :P

Comment: you can also try it https://github.com/quire-io/SwiftyChrono